# Add copy of data of and to an existing database with new tenant id

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant

we use a MySQL database and our data model is a multi-tenant model means every table has a column named "tenant_id" containing the id of an existing tenant. Very simplified example:

**Table: car**
Column: *id*
Column: *name*
Column: *tenantid*

**Table: licenseplate**
Column: *id*
Column: *carid* (foreign key to table car)
Column: *licenseplate*
Column: *tenantid*

Of course we have a set of data in this database - common style - means tables linked by foreign keys (auto-incremented integers) - currently mainly for testing purposes. Again simplified example:

**car:**
1 - BMW - CompanyA
2 - Porsche - CompanyA

**licenseplate:**
1 - 1 - MUC1234 - CompanyA
2 - 2 - EBE4321 - CompanyA

What I am looking for is a smart approach to
1) make a copy of the current data set
2) change the tenant_id for every table in the copied data set (e.g. from CompanyA to CompanyB)
3) add the copied/changed data set to the existing data base

This should help us to use the current data of one tenant as a base to create many other tenants within the same database.

Usually I just use mysql_dump to backup and restore but I cannot figure out how to keep foreign key relationships up for a copied set and how to change the tenant_id for all existing entries.

In the end the example should look like:

**car:**
1 - BMW - CompanyA
2 - Porsche - CompanyA
3 - BMW - CompanyB
4 - Porsche - CompanyB

**licenseplate:**
1 - 1 - MUC1234 - CompanyA
2 - 2 - EBE4321 - CompanyA
3 - 3 - MUC1234 - CompanyB
4 - 4 - EBE4321 - CompanyB

Does anyone have an idea? Usually I just need a direction where to go.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it via a copy service in code that gets the tenant specific data, updates the tenant id and then inserts. An so could be done.

IMHO the code based approach will be fine the ensure that the data is validated before copy.

Comment: Thanks - Was doing that now with a self-implemented code which creates a duplicate per row, updates the tenant and sets foreign keys to new duplicates as well - took me over a day - no complaint about that but to be honest I was hoping for a SQL solution, but probably that's not going to work.